# How to take first n rows of `ls` command

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

`ls` command outputs it's result by rows:

```
AndroidSandbox/                    kotlin-native-intellij/
arc-theme-macos/                   kotlin-native-sandbox/
BobkoLauncher/                     kotlin-ref-delegation/
...
```

How to take first `n` lines of this output? `ls | head -n 2` doesn't work because it will take two first files but I need two first lines of output.

Comment: This would be better suited for superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com, as one should not be programmatically consuming the output of `ls`.

Comment: @chepner : Your comment would be correct if the OP wanted to use `ls` to process a list of files. This doesn't seem to be the case here, where he explicitly is interested in part of the ls output, whatever this might be (and depending on the width of the terminal). This could be indeed be used inside a script.

Comment: And this is more a question about how to use a program than it is about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another note: both -C and -x when piped will use a default screen width. So you might want:

```
ls -C --width="$(tput cols)" | head
```

Answer (score 9):

Short answer:
`unbuffered ls | head -n 2`
explanation:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/how-to-trick-a-command-into-thinking-its-output-is-going-to-a-terminal

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you may want the output of

ls -C | head -2

Comment: Right. When you pipe the output of `ls`, you automatically get `ls -1` unless you provide an option like `-C`

Answer (score 0):

The reason `ls | head -n 2` only shows you the first two files is that the `ls` command detects that the output is not tty (it is the `|` instead) and changes its behavior accordingly.

If you use `ls -x | head -n 2` you will get the first two lines